# PHP Calendar IF statement with dates

Tags: php

In this calendar in php, I'm trying to change the css according to the month and day of the week. I need to make a function to separate the days that have passed and Saturday and Sunday and Set the class "cal_dayblock" and the rest of the days that do not yet passed and the next month they were in class cal_day

already tried several things and I'm not getting, please help me in this IF statement

```
<?php
$months = date("m");
$years = date("Y");
$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $months, $years);


for($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {


$date = $months.'/'.$i.'/'.$years;

if($i >= date('d') && $months >= date('m')) {
    echo '<div class="cal_day">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';}

else {
    echo '<div class="cal_dayblock">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';

}

echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

EDIT:

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function initialCalendar() {
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
showmonth = month;
showyear = year;
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
 }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "Carregando...";
    }
```

and PHP

```
     $showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
     $showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
     $showmonth = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $showmonth);
     $showyear = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $showyear);
```

getting error becouse that can help me fix it ? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to make a function to separate the days that have passed and Saturday and Sunday and Set the class "cal_dayblock"

**First part**

Day is in the past - just use `$date < date('d-m-Y')`

**Second part**

Day is a Saturday/Sunday: you can get the day name using either `D` or `l` (lowercase L) to get either Mon or Monday etc.

You will need to get this by creating a date in the format of `dd-mm-YYYY` because `strtotime()` doesn't like `mm/dd/YYYY` format.

Once you've got both of those conditions you can try this:

```
$day_count = date('t'); // get days in current month

$current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');

for($i = 1; $i <= $day_count; $i++) {
    $date_dmy = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($i . '-' . $current_month . '-' . $current_year));
    // get the day name using dd-mm-YYYY format for strtotime
    $day_name = date('D', strtotime($date_dmy));

    echo '<div class="cal_day';
    // do your separate logic here - if it's in the past or it's a Saturday or Sunday
    if($date_dmy < date('d-m-Y') || in_array($day_name, array('Sat', 'Sun')))
        echo 'block';

    // close the rest of your HTML
    echo '"><div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div></div>';
}
```

**Edit:** I'm just going to use `dd-mm-YYYY` format for **comparisons** here because even comparing dates in `m/d/Y` format with standard operators didn't work.

If you want to output the date in that format, do this:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date_dmy));
```

**Edit 2:** to tidy up this code even more, you could do this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $day_count; $i++) {
    $class_name = 'cal_day';

    $date_dmy = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($i . '-' . $current_month . '-' . $current_year));
    $day_name = date('D', strtotime($date_dmy));
    if($date_dmy < date('d-m-Y') || in_array($day_name, array('Sat', 'Sun')))
        $class_name .= 'block';

    $html = '<div class="%s"><div class="day_heading">%s</div></div>';
    echo sprintf($html, $class_name, $i);
}
```

**Docs:**

- [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)
- [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: Great! but if my month and year variables comming from a javascript date() post to php.. i've edited the code

Comment: replace `$current_year` and `$current_month` with `$showyear` and `$showmonth` - assuming your AJAX is working correctly.